# Run/load function when there is a form on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The following script link, is linking to a JavaScript file that handle form validation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/form-validation.js"></script>
```

And it is included to all the pages using PHP include, the question is; how do I only make it run or even load when there is a form on the page?

I tried this: `$('form').load('form-validation.js', function(){ /* callback */ });`
But did not work, I also searched and did not find a real answer...

Comment: Why are you including it with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**jQuery.getScript()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), it load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

You can use `.length` property to check form exists or not.

```
if ($('form').length) {
  $.getScript('form-validation.js', function () {
    /* callback */
  });
}
```

### EDIT

There is no option to add it to the JS file it self, and make it work

```
//Place this code at the top of your form-validation.js file
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('form').length > 0) {
      //Do validation
    }
});
```

Comment: So basically wrap the script with that?

Comment: @Loai, You need to place this block in your HTML page if page has form , it will load your validation script

Comment: So I don't insert my function inside where it says CALLBACK. But I add that line in the HTML page where there is a form? so I have to add it in every page that has a form?

Comment: Please I don't understand where to exactly place it

Comment: @Loai, __so I have to add it in every page that has a form?__. Yes

Comment: There is no option to add it to the JS file it self, and make it work? so I only need to add it once... please as the website has to be dynamic - it is a basic template

Comment: @Loai, Yes, there is an option

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47155/discussion-between-loai-and-satpal)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to do it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('form').length>0) {
  $.getScript('form-validation.js', function () {

  });
 }});
 </script>
```